# Learning PHP after Excel VBA

Tags: php

I'm essentially a finance person with a very steep slant towards Excel VBA. I've learnt a lot from this forum. I'm thinking of taking up PHP and eventually javascript. Today is day 0, so before I began I just wanted to ask if anyone's gone from no programming experience to Excel VBA to PHP.. are there any minefields to look out for?

Comment: If you start that way, I think you're starting wrong. Get some practice first, then ask.

Comment: I unfortunately know some (*some*) VBA. I've written a few programs and scripts with VBA. I knew JS and PHP before I learned VBA, and there were some bumps and curves and pitfalls. They're different. Alot different. Quirks aside, a lot of the terminology is different, the whitespacing is completely different, and PHP is more verbal than the cross-eyed chipmunk squawks Perl subjects you to, it's still less literal and more symbolic than VBA. You gotta be dedicated, but you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big minefield between 'desktop' and 'web' programming is that webpages are based on request and response. That basically means that your PHP script is a short program that only generates a small piece of HTML. After the user clicks something in their browser, a new request is fired to the same or a different script. So instead of one continuous program, you've got a lot of small programs and a very clear line between the server side code and the client side code.

That might actually be very similary to VBA programming, where you probably have relatively small macros that are triggered by the user using the Excel interface, so maybe it's an easier step for you than for a 'real' desktop programmer (no offence).

Comment: `PHPhffft! vs. VBAaaargh!` Yeah, he might have some other issues. The whitespace, the syntax, the lexicon, the braindeadedness.